# Prove weak formulation of linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A: V\to V$ be a linear mapping and $Af=u$ where $u,f\in V$.

The weak formulation of $Af=u$ is $\langle Af,v \rangle$=$\langle u,v \rangle$ for all $v\in V.$

1. Prove that if $Af=u$ holds, then $\langle Af,v \rangle$=$\langle u,v \rangle$.

If I understood correctly, I have to prove that the inner product properties hold. Since $Au=f$ holds, then $Af-u=0$. Now, prove that

a) $\langle Af,v \rangle$=$\langle v,Af \rangle$

b) $\langle Af-u,v \rangle = \langle Af,v\rangle + \langle u,v\rangle$

c) $\langle c(Af-u),v\rangle=c\langle Af-u,v\rangle$

d) $\langle Af-u,Af-u\rangle \ge 0,$ and $\langle Af-u,Af-u\rangle =0 $ if and only if $Af-u=0.$

I know how to prove all of them except b) but on the other hand, I'm also quite unsure if I even understood the exercise right. The second part of the task asks

2. Let's assume $\langle Af,v \rangle$=$\langle u,v \rangle$ holds for some $v\in V$. Does this also mean that $Af=u$ holds?

I don't know to approach this at all. Should I somehow start with the inner product properties?

Comment: Hint: If $Af = u$, then $\left \langle Af-u,v \right \rangle = \left \langle 0 , v \right \rangle $ for all $v$.

Comment: @DanielLautzenheiser Thank you for your answer! Is the hint for 1b) and is it possible for you to hint if I understood the exercise correctly?

Comment: Joe: I believe property 1b should read $ \left \langle Af-u,v \right\rangle = \left\langle Af, v \right\rangle - \left\langle u,v \right\rangle$. Since you are working in an inner-product space environment, you don't need to re-prove the inner-product properties, they're given! For part 2., try to come up with a counterexample first...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have misunderstood the first part of the problem.  We are given a space $V$ that comes with an inner-product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ over that space.  The proof of 1, then, is very simple ("trivial", perhaps).

> Suppose that $Af = u$.  Then for all $v \in V$, we have
>   $$
> \langle Af,v \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle.
> $$

For the second part: the answer to the question is no.  We can construct a counterexample with $V = \Bbb R^2$ as follows: take $A$ to be the identity map, take $f = (1,0)$, take $u = (2,0)$, and take $v = (0,1)$.